# Get the url of active tab of a browser in C on OSX

Tags: c, browser-api

Is it possible to get the URL of current tab of a Browser in C? I can do it using AppleScript but I want to use C language. Maybe I calling system, I don't know.help me please

Comment: Possible? Certainly. How to? Too broad.

Comment: Maybe a browser has some API ?

Comment: What Browser? Isn't that at least a reasonable thing to specify?

Comment: If you can do it with AppleScript, you can send the corresponding [AppleEvents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_event) from C. I think you can also compile and execute AppleScript from C. Consult the XCode help system. You can also execute AppleScript using the `osascript` command (see `man osascript`).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the [accessibility framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/applicationservices) to get the url for both Safari and Chrome (verified). The API is entirely in C but you do need to link to the `ApplicationServices` framework.